# Cannot Watch Folder using FileSystemWatcher in C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, .net

I am attempting to monitor a folder (and its sub-folders) for changes. However, my handler event is never executed. I am using the following code:

```
FileSystemWatcher m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
m_Watcher.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/Portal 2 Map Installer/"; 
m_Watcher.Filter = "";
m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
             NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
             NotifyFilters.FileName |
             NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
m_Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
m_Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFolderChange);
m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Help please!

Comment: That code looks correct to me. The problem must lie elsewhere. What type of file system are you trying to watch? This doesn't work with FAT32 partitions, for example.

Comment: I think I've figured it out! For some reason my Form1_Load event is not triggering, which is where I do all of the initialisation. Now to track down why.

Comment: Alright, got it working! Now does anyone know how to stop the events being triggered three times? I get the created event triggered, then two changed events.

Comment: @Yoshie: You should set properties like this in the constructor: `public Form1()`, rather than in the `Load` event handler method.

Comment: You can't stop the event being triggered several times, so you have to work around that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449993/vb-net-filesystemwatcher-multiple-change-events for some suggestions.

Comment: If you are writing for windows 7 ... there is a similar filesystem event watcher in the win7api codepack you may want to have a look at

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler for the on error event and see what it says:

```
  m_Watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
```

Comment: Error 3 The property or indexer 'Portal_2_Level_Installer.Form1.OnError' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Comment: Error 4 'Portal_2_Level_Installer.Form1.OnError' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

Comment: @YoshieMaster: You need to define your OnError handler first.

Answer (score 0):

There are some notes on the [`Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx) event handler :

> The Changed event is raised unexpectedly when a file is renamed, but is not raised when a directory is renamed. To watch for renaming, use the [Renamed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed.aspx) event.

So it would be prudent to handle the [`Renamed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed.aspx) event as well (at the least).

Comment: The folder or it's contents will never be erased. Files are placed into the folder, acted on, then deleted.