# I need to handle even only once

Tags: c#, events

I am tying to write App that would check if the text file was changes. And if it was, it's restart the Windows service.

I am using FileSystemWatcher for it, and it's look like it's generate few events. Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class FileMon
    {
        public static bool status;

        public static void Run()
        {
          try
            {

                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = @"D:\test\";
                watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                Console.WriteLine(status);
                while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }

        static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ChangeType);
          //  status = true;
            Console.WriteLine(status);


            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine("before IF block status = {0} ", status);

            if (status == false)
            {
                RestartService();
                status = true;
                Console.WriteLine("after IF block status = {0} ", status);
            }

            else
            {

            }

        }


        public static void RestartService()
        {


            ServiceController service = new ServiceController("6to4");
            try
            {
                int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;

                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
                Console.WriteLine("trying to stop");

                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

           //     Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("stoping.........");

                // count the rest of the timeout
            //    int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            //    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50 - (millisec2 - millisec1));

                Console.WriteLine("dd");
              //  Console.ReadKey();

                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

            }
            catch
            {
                // ...
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I run it, and change text file at text editor I get next output:

```
False
Changed
False
File: D:\test\1.txt Changed
before IF block status = False
trying to stop
after IF block status = True
Changed
True
File: D:\test\1.txt Changed
before IF block status = True
Changed
True
File: D:\test\1.txt Changed
before IF block status = True
```

It's look like somewhere there is bug, thats why after single changing I see not one, but three copy of output. And I can't understand what's wrong and where I did mistake....

Comment: You're not likely to get too much help if you habitually don't accept any answers to your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET FileSystemWatcher Multiple Change Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449993/vb-net-filesystemwatcher-multiple-change-events)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `FileSystemWatcher`. It is not bullet proof perfect and sometimes produces multiple events for a *single* change and it is also possible that events are not raised after a change if these occur on a high rate.

So your workaround about using the flag `status` is all you can do to react on these odd behaviors of the `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: Their is no bug in *your* code. Your method `watcher_Changed()` will simply called three times by the `FileSystemWatcher`.