# Why is FileSystemWatcher raising Changed event when file is created?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, filesystemwatcher

This is my code:

```
 _instrumentsFolderWatcher.Changed += _instrumentsFolderWatcher_Changed;
 _instrumentsFolderWatcher.Created += _instrumentsFolderWatcher_Created;
 _instrumentsFolderWatcher.Deleted += _instrumentsFolderWatcher_Deleted;
```

where `_instrumentsFolderWatcher` is instance of `FileSystemWatcher`. Problem is when I paste a file in the folder which is being monitored, both the created and changed events are fired. Why would changed event be fired? Further the changed event is fired with `ChangeType` of Changed. How do I get around this issue?

`Edit:` Why is Changed event not fired when I change the filename?

Comment: When you "paste" the file, the new file is both being created and changed. Can you explain how this causes an issue for you?

Comment: Hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449993/vb-net-filesystemwatcher-multiple-change-events

Comment: @William: If it is so obvious, next question is why would changed event be fired 2 times?

Comment: @Jack: I didn't intend to indicate that anything was obvious, only that if I had a better understanding of why multiple events caused you trouble I may be able to suggest a way to mitigate the issue. Changing the file name should result in a `Renamed` event. You may find the documentation at [File System Watcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) useful. Specifically the section in Remarks titled "Events and Buffer Sizes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.

Try using the `Renamed` event to determine when a file is renamed.