# c# FileSystemWatcher triggers twice when listening to OnChanged

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Trying to implement `FileSystemWatcher` but the `OnChanged` function is called twice when the file is saved.  based on some other posts, I suspect the `LastWrite` filter has multiple events?  I thought the `NotifyFilters` would limit it to only firing when the file is written to, but something else is causing the function to run twice. `e.ChangeType` only tells me the file changed, but not exactly how.  Is there a way to limit this to running only once?

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (newString == null)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
            {
                lastString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            difference = lastString;
        } else {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
            {
                newString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            int newCount = newString.Count();
            int count = lastString.Count();
            // MessageBox.Show("last:" + lastString.Count().ToString(), "next: " + newString.Count());
            difference = newString.Remove(0,5);
            lastString = newString;
        }
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { tb_content.Text = difference; }));
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChangeType.ToString(), "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter it out yourself, as I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449993/vb-net-filesystemwatcher-multiple-change-events/450046#450046).

Comment: I think your URL got messed up

Comment: You were just to fast :)

Comment: perfect fix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Frederik's answer:

A small workaround that comes to mind would be to prevent the OnChanged method from executing if it is already executing.

For example:

```
private bool IsExecuting { get; set; }

private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsExecuting) 
    {
        IsExecuting = true;

        // rest of your code

        IsExecuting = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the method I used a short while back, works well

Comment: This doesn't work, still goes in the method. 
Correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice